# warning: trying to access array offset on value of type bool ACF field image group

Tags: functions, custom-field, images, advanced-custom-fields, errors

I have a problem with an acf function for displaying an image by array.

I can get my image to work well when I upload it to the field associated with it.
On the other hand, when I don't put an image, because the field is not mandatory, I get this error `warning: trying to access array offset on value of type bool`

My image field is in a field group, in a page option and I'm in php 8.0

My code looks like this

```
<?php
$image = get_field('my_group','option');
$image_name = $image ['my_img'];
if ($image):?>
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url ($image_name['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image_name['alt']); ?>" />
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$image` and `$image_name` are arrays? The warning you're getting indicates that you're trying to treat a boolean value (ie, either `true` or `false`) as an array.

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong.
In any case my goal is to use the example from the acf doc for "display image (array)"
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

Comment: You'll have to check with ACF support about this. I do suggest you check to see if your `get_field()` call is returning an array and not, say, `false`.